# Deserialize array of strings to csv

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json payload with:

```
"host_names": [
    "www.host1.com",
    "www.host2.com"
]
```

How can I deserialize this as a csv using Jackson - e.g.:

```
"www.host1.com,www.host2.com"
```

Previously I was deserializing this as a `String[]` but I can't persist that with hibernate, so now I'm trying to deserialize it as a csv.

EDIT:

I want to use annotations to turn the json array into a string, where each element of the array is separated by a comma. Perhaps something like `@JsonRawValue`. The goal is to then persist the value to a data via hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonStr = "{\"host_names\": [\r\n" + 
                "    \"www.host1.com\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"www.host2.com\"\r\n" + 
                "]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray hostNames = jsonObject.getJSONArray("host_names");
        String result = "";
        for(int i=0;i<hostNames.length(); i++) {
            if(!result.isEmpty())
            result = result+",\""+hostNames.getString(i)+"\"";
            else
                result = "\""+hostNames.getString(i)+"\"";
        }
        System.out.println(result); 
    }
```

result

```
"www.host1.com","www.host2.com"
```

**Other approach based on annotation**

Create a class

```
class Server{
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "host_names")
    private List<String> hostNames;

    public List<String> getHostNames() {
        return hostNames;
    }

    public void setHostNames(List<String> hostNames) {
        this.hostNames = hostNames;
    }
}
```

Now use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to parse the `JSON` into this class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String jsonStr = "{\"host_names\": [\r\n" + 
                "    \"www.host1.com\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"www.host2.com\"\r\n" + 
                "]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Server server = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Server.class);
        System.out.println(server.getHostNames());
    }
```

output

```
[www.host1.com, www.host2.com]
```

Comment: Is there a way using annotations? Such as JsonFormat?

Comment: @eddie-ryan updated my answer , let me know if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. I'm trying to use annotations to deserialize the string[] in the json to a string (csv). I'm currently using code similar to your approach

Comment: what exactly u mean by string csv ? is there any particular format u want , if u can help me to understand the scenario  better

Comment: like your first example 'www.host1.com,www.host2.com'. So the json contains an array, of strings, I want to deserialize that into a string where each piece of text is separated by a comma. Essentially, your first approach, but using annotations

Comment: @eddie-ryan updated my first approach to get what u want, working on the second to get the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your `setter` / `getter` for `host_names` property as

**Bean Class**

```
public class Server {

    @JsonProperty("host_names")
    private List<String> hostNames;

    @JsonGetter("host_names")
    public String getHostNames() {
        return String.join(",", hostNames);
    }

    @JsonSetter("host_names")
    public void setHostNames(List<String> hostNames) {
        this.hostNames = hostNames;
    }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Server server = mapper.readValue("{\"host_names\":[\"www.host1.com\",\"www.host2.com\"]}", Server.class);
    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(server);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "host_names" : "www.host1.com,www.host2.com"
}
```

This way you can serialize as comma separated string, and array of string while deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution using `@JsonValue` Annotation.
Define your bean class as:

```
public class Server {

    @JsonProperty("host_names")
    private List<String> hostNames;

    @JsonValue
    public String hostNames() {
        return String.join(",", hostNames);
    }

    public List<String> getHostNames() {
        return hostNames;
    }

    public void setHostNames(List<String> hostNames) {
        this.hostNames = hostNames;
    }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Server server = mapper.readValue("{\"host_names\":[\"www.host1.com\",\"www.host2.com\"]}", Server.class);
    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(server);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

**Output**

```
"www.host1.com,www.host2.com"
```

This method will only be useful if your bean class has no other fields to serialize.